# Can you install stone veneer at an angle?

Tags: masonry, stone

I'm thinking of covering my brick fireplace with 6"x24" stone veneer panels and wondered about doing something like setting all the rows on an angle or having the left and right sides each angled up to meet at a peak in the center.

I know I'd have to be really careful to provide support, since the panels would want to slide, but would the final result be less stable once the thin set dries?

Comment: Seems like you would have to start with the lowest layer (course) of veneer stones cut into triangles or at least with on diagonal side. Then the remaining layers would build up on this. So to the extent the lower levels support the upper as the thinset is setting this would be similar to a conventional 90 degree installation. Depending on the angle maybe you would have some side-slip to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can set them in angled patterns. The aesthetics are a separate question. Do keep in mind that in addition to the spacers you're likely adding a number of cuts that you wouldn't have otherwise.

Comment: I agree and have done angled jobs in the past, more cuts but I think it looks better than the standard horizontal layout.+